# Phalcon: How to get first model in 1-n relation

Tags: php, model, phalcon

I have the following models

```
class Post extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    ...
    $this->hasMany('id', 'PostMedia', 'parent_id');
}

class PostMedia extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    ...
    $this->belongsTo('parent_id', 'Post', 'id');
}
```

To get all related entries I do the following

```
Post::find(1)->postMedia;
```

But how do I get just the first model? The following code results in a `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple` object, but I need the PostMedia object.

```
Post::find(1)->getPostMedia(['limit' => 1]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are `getFirst()`, `getLast()` and other useful methods in the `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple` class. Also there is another problem in your code: `Post::find(1)` returns resultset, not Post object, so the correct code to get first related object will look like this:

```
$first_media = Post::findFirst(1)->postMedia->getFirst();
```